# react native modal not opening

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, touchableopacity

I am trying to launch a modal on a simple click of a button, but for whatever reason the modal doesn't appear to be launching

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { View, Alert, ScrollView, Text, Modal, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Actions from '../Actions/Creators'
import { Actions as NavigationActions } from 'react-native-router-flux'
import CartRow from '../Components/CartRow'
import CartTotal from '../Components/CartTotal'
import RoundedButton from '../Components/RoundedButton'

// Styles
import styles from './Styles/CartAndCheckoutStyle'

class CartAndCheckout extends React.Component {

   constructor (props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       modalVisible: false
     }
   }

   setModalVisible(visible) {
     this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
     console.log(visible)
   }

   static propTypes = {
     items: PropTypes.array,
   }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.currentBalance}>
          <Text style={styles.currentBalanceTitle}>CURRENT BALANCE</Text>
          <Text style={styles.currentBalanceAmount}>$0.00</Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
          <Modal
            animationType={"slide"}
            transparent={false}
            visible={this.state.modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
            >
           <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
            <View>
              <Text>Hello World!</Text>
            </View>
           </View>
          </Modal>
          <View style={styles.cartItems}>
            {(this.props.items||[]).map((section,i) => (
              <CartRow key={i} action={this.setQty} index={i} element={section} />
            ))}
          </View>
          <CartTotal items={this.props.items||[]} />
        </ScrollView>
        <RoundedButton onPress={()=>{this.setModalVisible(true)}} text='Place Order' />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

CartAndCheckout.propTypes = {
  updateCart: PropTypes.func,
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    // items: state.cart.items,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateCart: (index,qty) => dispatch(Actions.updateCart(index,qty)),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CartAndCheckout)
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.setModalVisible(true).bind(this)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using react-native-router-flux but you don't show us the Scene setup. If you look at the (https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/OTHER_INFO.md#modals) documentation you will see that

'To display a modal use Modal as root renderer, so it will render the first element as normal scene and all others as popups (when they are pushed). For example:'

```
import StatusModal from './components/StatusModal'

<Router>
  <Scene key="modal" component={Modal} >
    <Scene key="root">
      <Scene key="screen1" initial={true} component={Screen1} />
      <Scene key="screen2" component={Screen2} />
    </Scene>
    <Scene key="statusModal" component={StatusModal} />
  </Scene>
</Router>
```

You should not be rendering a modal deep in your components. You need a modal Scene wrapper around root in which you can embed any modal scenes as siblings to root.

Comment: this isnt a navigation path, its just a prompt box. I have found that issue needs to be related to RN43+ and using the remote debug. Once I have disable remote debug it seems to work, though I am still not sure this is the ideal solution

Comment: also this seems to cause the modal to only render half across the screen

Comment: Sounds like a style issue. Set the modal container to { position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `<Modal>` is inside a `<ScrollView>`. It should be placed as a sibling to the ScrollView. Try putting the Modal after the `<RoundedButton>` in your JSX. Since the Modal creates a full-screen view, there's no need to place it inside a ScrollView.

Comment: same result the button changes opacity, and the console log shows me that its sending a result of `true` but no modal :S